# Symbolic geometry not working?

Tags: bugs, geometry, raspberry-pi

**Bug fixed in 10.0.0+2014080602**

---

I have Mathematica 10 on the Raspberry Pi. (wolfram-engine version 10.0.0+2013112003)

According to the "What's New in Mathematica 10" page http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/symbolic-geometry/compute-measures-length-area-volume-etc.html , I should be able to say:

```
In[1]:= ArcLength[Circle[]]
Out[1]= 2π
```

What I actually see is:

```
In[1]:= ArcLength[Circle[]]
Out[1]= ArcLength[Circle[{0, 0}]]
```

and similarly for all other geometric examples on that page. Is this a Mathematica bug, or a Raspberry Pi bug, or a my understanding bug?

Comment: It works in 10.0.1 under Windows.  Perhaps it is a Raspberry Pi limitation.  I seem to recall reading that the R-P distribution lacks geodesy functionality for example.  This of course should be disclosed.

Comment: Seems to work on OS X too; but not on RPi. "And it’s the whole system. Nothing is left out. All 5000+ Wolfram Language functions. All capabilities of Mathematica and its notebook interface." ( http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/11/21/putting-the-wolfram-language-and-mathematica-on-every-raspberry-pi/ ) Apparently not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring Stephen's [marketing hype](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/11/21/putting-the-wolfram-language-and-mathematica-on-every-raspberry-pi/), it's important to recognize that the RPi distribution is stripped down a bit so that it can be bundled onto the computer (I think the latest version is 400 MB).  This issue was more recently addressed with the `Sunrise` and `Sunset` functions over at [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/317901):

> Yes. We strive to keep the Raspberry Pi distribution as small as possible to keep it sensible for bundling. The underlying component that provides this is particularly large, so it was a known omission.

That said, `ArcLength[Circle[]]` works as designed on the August 4th, 2014 version,<sup>1</sup> and you probably should consider upgrading.

---

<sup>1</sup> I suspect this issue can be considered a bug and will tag the question as such.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had the latest version but it turns out that neither http://repository.wolfram.com nor http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ have updated versions. Anyone coming across this later: you need to grab it from the main Raspberry Pi repository: http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/w/wolfram-engine/

Comment: @SimonCozens does this mean that the newest version is working? Then you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @YvesKlett The August 4th version is the latest one.  I think the problem here is that earlier versions of wolfram would be "kept back" during a `sudo apt-get upgrade`, and Simon's solution is one way around this.